# Does .edmx files used in real world

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, edmx

I am reading in the [book](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043) where author create custom context class (*not using edmx file*) for data access.
I wonder now.
In real world scenario what is most used method custom `DbContext` class **or** `.edmx` file(s).
I know that I should have different `.edmx` files if I use them but do I need to have the same if I use custom `DbContext` class.

Comment: depends, code first or database first.

Comment: I always design database first.

Comment: i like code first with migrations (ie no edmx) as it means that everything is in source control, however this is a very subjective question

Comment: I always use EF Power Tools to reverse-engineer existing database into 'code-first' mappings, but I agree with Luke, it's very subjective.

Comment: We're running with the edmx. However this can be a real pain when it is under source control and conflicts occur, rather than having a set of classes to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using database or model first you have to have the edmx file - it is embedded in the dll, and the connection string references it. It contains the mapping information.

If using code first you never need an edmx file - the mapping information is derived by convention and/or by code (i.e. attributes etc). (Creating a custom DbContext is the code first approach)

The code first approach hasn't been around as long as the database first approach, and therefore I would guess is more prevalent in real world scenarios. It is also more likely that a database first approach would be used when an existing database structure exists. However, the code first approach is rapidly gaining popularity.